# I'm having a problem connecting a database table to a report at run-time in Microsoft ReportViewer in VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a production reporting app for a small manufacturing company.  Production data is added to an MSAccess database using the VB.Net interface and then the user can select a month and the monthly production is displayed using MS ReportViewer and a predesigned report stored in a file called Report1.rdlc.  Before the report is loaded, I create the report data in a temporary table in the database and the location of the database is fed to the report viewer at run-time.  The problem is that it works in the development environment, but not in the deployed executable.

```
Private Sub frmReport_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Get the location of the data file from the configuration file
    Dim strConnectString As String
    strConnectString = ""

    FileOpen(1, "ProdPlan.cfg", OpenMode.Input)
    Input(1, strConnectString)
    FileClose(1)
    strConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " & strConnectString

    ' Add the local data file as the new data source for the report
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", strConnectString))
    Me.DataTable1BindingSource.DataSource = DataSet1
    Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = strConnectString
    Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.DataTable1)
    Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.GetData()

    ' Set the printing settings for the report

    Dim pageSettings = New Printing.PageSettings()

    pageSettings.PaperSize = New Printing.PaperSize("Custom", 850, 1100)
    pageSettings.Landscape = True
    pageSettings.Margins.Left = 75
    pageSettings.Margins.Right = 75
    pageSettings.Margins.Top = 75
    pageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 75

    Me.ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pageSettings)

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

When I first open the deployed program and run a report, it runs fine, but then when I add new data to the database, the report no longer runs.  The form comes up OK, but there is no data in the report.  When I check in the database, the data is there, and the temporary reporting table is filled correctly.  I suspect the problem is that the report viewer is somehow losing the connection to the database when new data is added, but I have no clue as to why that would happen in the run-time version and not the development version.  I'm connecting the database to the report every time I load the report form, as shown in the code segment.

Comment: do you have your executable file signed? If computers in your company are in domain, you need to generate certificate (My Project - signing)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Peter.  I checked and the project is signed and there is a certificate that's good until Sep 2020.  The problem happens on my personal PC as well, not just the company's computers.

Comment: Update:  I have found a work-around that works, but it's very "brute-force".  If I force the program to restart before showing the report, it works.  It's a bit slow, and as I said, not very elegant, so any suggestions would still be very welcome.